# c++ design: inheritance and returning opaque handles

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-safety

I have two interfaces that looks like this:

```
class IThing {
    ...
    virtual IHandle* getHandle(void) = 0;
    virtual void useHandle(IHandle *handle) = 0;
};

class IHandle { ... }
```

I want users to be able to implement IThing and IHandle.  For example, if a user creates `MyThing` and `MyHandle`, `getHandle` should return a pointer to a `MyHandle`, which the user can later use in `useHandle`.

This will work, but I don't like the design because multiple implementations of `IHandle` can get mixed up between implementations of `IThing`.  Also in `useHandle`, users will need to explicitly downcast to their implementation of `IHandle`.  Is there a more type-safe way to do this?

Comment: You might want to read up on polymorphism.   More often than not, expecting to use downcasting in situations like this is a sign that polymorphism is not being used effectively in the design or implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of what you want to design.  But here some thoughts that I hope could be helpful.

The basic principle is that classes publicly derived from `IThing` are indeed `IThing`.  So eveything that you can do with `IThing`, you can do with `MyThing`, including getting an `IHandle`.

There's no design issue, as long as your `IHandle` derivates all obey to the same principle.  This means that your things shouldn't make any assumptions about the specific handles and vice versa.

If however you make use in the implementation of `MyHandle` of assumptions that it's linked with `MyThing` (or vice versa), you'll get into the troubles you describe.  In fact you use a dependency that is not expressed in your class definition. So yes, you'll have to use downcast. It's unconfortable, because it reveals a desing issue.

As your classes are polymorphic, you can limit downcasting risks by checking for nullptr with `dynamic_cast`.  But this is a workaround, not a design improvement.

Alternatively you could consider templates.  They could help you to link related types at compile time. You'll gain on type safety, but you'll loose some flexibility of runtime polymorphism.  One example approach:

```
template <class IH>
class IThing  {   
public:
    virtual IH* getHandle(void) =0;
    virtual void useHandle(IH *handle) =0;
};

class MyHandle {  };  // to keep it simple, 

class MyThing: public IThing<MyHandle> {}; // instantiation with specific handle

int main() {
    MyThing i; 
    MyHandle *h;
    h = i.getHandle(); 
    ...
 }
```

The constraint in this example, is that you don't mix different `IThings` using different handles.